# "App.framework does not support provisioning profiles" when trying to build my flutter app with codemagic

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I'm trying to build and release my flutter app for development purposes (to test it with testmagic) with codemagic (because I'm using a windows machine). But everytime I build the app the step `build` fails and the following error shows up:

```
Unable to export archive: 2020-01-05 05:46:47.914 xcodebuild[1398:9643] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/r7/d9twdq011sb8d3q1p8f39cdr0000gn/T/Runner_2020-01-05_05-46-47.912.xcdistributionlogs'. error: exportArchive: App.framework does not support provisioning profiles. Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=10 "App.framework does not support provisioning profiles." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription=App.framework does not support provisioning profiles., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=App.framework does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile {Name of the App + ID} has been manually specified. Remove this item from the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.} ** EXPORT FAILED **
```

---

There's a part in the error message which says I should remove and item from the `provisioningProfiles` dictionary:

```
 Remove this item from the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.
```

I don't understand what this means. I've tried with deleting the automatic generated provisioning profile from my apple developer account but this doesn't work.

---

The build settings:

[image: codemagic build settings]

The code signing settings:

[image: codemagic code signing settings]

I don't have any idea why this is happening. I found some github issues about a similar probelm on the internet but every issue is still open and not active or for xcode users and I'm not using xcode.

Comment: Hi, can you check your podfile and this solution? https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8675#issuecomment-502126252

Comment: Hey. Where should this `podfile` be? Can't find it.

Comment: usually in `ios` folder if you use cocoapods

Comment: I don‘t use it thats the funny part. I don‘t even know what this is..

Comment: Hi, we need additional info like build link to help with this question. But I guess it's better to continue in Codemagic slack community. You can find the link on Codemagic site

Comment: @MikhailTokarev Thank you for your help. I change to your slack channel.

Comment: Did you find the fix? Would you be so kind to share it with us (as an answer on your own question)?

Comment: I haven't found a solution so I've bought an old iMac to build my app because I've lost patience with codemagic.

Comment: Wow, that tough to hear. I hope I'll find a fix

Comment: @Floris I'll try it again one day because codemagic would be an amazing solution to automatically build and deploy apps but for now my iMac is doing the job.

Answer (score 11):

Old issue but I think this solution should apply to people who stumble upon this again. Usually this only affects users that are trying to build without a Mac and then they edit every instance of 'BundleIdentifier' they can find.

The fix is to open up your AppFrameworksInfo.plist file and change the CFBundleIdentifier to io.flutter.flutter.app instead of your bundle ID.

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>io.flutter.flutter.app</string>
```

Comment: This my good sir has been a life saver. Have been banging my head the whole day trying to get things to build and this finally got it to work. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CI/CD (e.g Azure DevOpps) and passing xcodebuild command line build configuration arguments, e.g `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` or `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER` it will be also be passed downn to the other pods projects. As @arnold-veltmann said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64611361/534349) the culprit is passing `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` to projects (`pods`) that do not support signing. In my case it's for a project using `Ionic 5` with `Capacitor` which make uses of cocoapods.

The usual `post_install` solution in pods file did not work for me

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
      end
    end
end
```

Although I did check and the post_install run and sets the build config correctly.

What I ended up doing was create a custom build setting e.g `SP_PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` and pass it in the azure devops yaml pipeline xcode build step

```
 - task: Xcode@5
    displayName: 'Build iOS app'
    inputs:
      actions: 'build'
      configuration: 'Appcenter'
      sdk: 'iphoneos'
      xcWorkspacePath: 'ios/App/App.xcworkspace'
      scheme: 'App'
      xcodeVersion: '11'
      packageApp: true
      archivePath: './output'
      exportPath: './output'
      exportOptions: 'plist'
      exportOptionsPlist: './_deploy/Appcenter-ExportOptions.plist'
      signingOption: 'default'
      args: SP_PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=$(bundleIdentifier) SP_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=$(iosProvisioningProfile)
```

Afterwards in the `project.pbxproj` I've located my build configuration used for Appcenter (CI/CD) build and set

```
E6D3FFF3256E6D8500109D05 /* Appcenter */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            baseConfigurationReference = A158677F50F9AF6793C0B6F1 /* Pods-App.appcenter.xcconfig */;
            buildSettings = {
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
                CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = App/App.entitlements;
                CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "iPhone Distribution";
                CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Manual;
                DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = B982UY6B4T;
                INFOPLIST_FILE = App/Info.plist;
                IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12.0;
                LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks";
                PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "$(SP_PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)";
                PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = "$(SP_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER)";
                SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS = USE_PUSH;
                SWIFT_VERSION = 5.0;
                TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1;
            };
            name = Appcenter;
        };
```

Notice the `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = "$(SP_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER)";`

I hope this helps someone, because I spent 1 day, building a thousand times and failing 1001 more.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer to you question, but I managed to create a build pipeline for the Flutter `Android` & `IOS` app starter-template **without** the need for a physical `macOS` device.

All steps with the source code are [documented here](https://github.com/FlorisDevreese/Flutter-CI-CD).

Hope this helps!